# Getting value from Task with lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda, async-await, task

I wrote a simple code which POST credential to a website. I need the return value but I get a null which results to `ArgumentException`. How can I do this properly

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim routerUri = "http://127.0.0.1/login.cgi"
        Dim routerMethod = "POST"
        Dim routerPostData = New Specialized.NameValueCollection From {
                {"username", ""},
                {"password", ""},
                {"foo", "bar"}
            }
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(GetResponse(routerUri, routerMethod, routerPostData)))
    End Sub
    Function GetResponse(hUri As String, hMethod As String, rqParam As Specialized.NameValueCollection)
        Dim uriUri As New Uri(hUri)
        Dim rByte
        Dim tTask = New Task(
            Async Sub()
                Dim task As Task(Of Byte()) = SendRequest(uriUri, hMethod, rqParam)
                rByte = Await task
            End Sub)
        tTask.Start()
        tTask.Wait()
        Return rByte
    End Function

    Async Function SendRequest(hUri As Uri, hMethod As String, rqParam As Specialized.NameValueCollection) As Task(Of Byte())
        Dim rByte As Byte()
        Using client As New WebClient
            rByte = Await client.UploadValuesTaskAsync(hUri, hMethod, rqParam)
        End Using
        Return rByte
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers allow for Async Subs so it would be better to just make the handler async and call the async function directly. Avoid creating new `Task`s manually.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim routerUri = "http://127.0.0.1/login.cgi"
    Dim routerMethod = "POST"
    Dim routerPostData = New Specialized.NameValueCollection From {
            {"username", ""},
            {"password", ""},
            {"foo", "bar"}
        }
    Dim bytes = Await GetResponseAsync(routerUri, routerMethod, routerPostData)
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes))
End Sub
```

Where `GetResponseAsync` is

```
Async Function GetResponseAsync(hUri As String, hMethod As String, rqParam As Specialized.NameValueCollection) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim uriUri As New Uri(hUri)
    Return Await SendRequest(uriUri, hMethod, rqParam)        
End Function
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: I see that it spawns its own thread. What part of the code where it actually does that?

Comment: @conquistador review the link provided in the answer.